# Extract each value from JSON array as unique row

Tags: sql, arrays, json, presto

Here is my Presto query

```
%jdbc(presto)
select
    cast(json_extract(basicmetadata, '$.locales') as array<map<varchar, json>>)
from 
    escherbird.entities
where
    entityid = 1262415487625019394
    and domainid = 124
```

It returns this array

```
[{country="IN", hashCode=1828207720, _passthroughFields={}, language="en"}, {country="AU", hashCode=1899888409, _passthroughFields={}, language="en"}, {country="GB", hashCode=-2002878675, _passthroughFields={}, language="en"}, {country="IE", hashCode=-358794848, _passthroughFields={}, language="en"}, {country="CA", hashCode=392726027, _passthroughFields={}, language="en"}, {country="NZ", hashCode=-136386876, _passthroughFields={}, language="en"}, {country="US", hashCode=-1355251774, _passthroughFields={}, language="en"}]
```

This query gives me a null result

```
%jdbc(presto)
select
    cast(json_extract(basicmetadata, '$.locales.country') as array<map<varchar, json>>)
from 
    escherbird.entities
where
    entityid = 1262415487625019394
    and domainid = 124
```

How do I write a query to return each country as a unique row?

Comment: Please tag your question with the databse that you are running: mysql, postgresql, oracle...? JSON functions are highly vendor-specific.

Comment: Please add the sql statement you used to fetch this.

Comment: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query which runs in **SQL server 2016** and above,

```
DECLARE @JSONDATA NVARCHAR(MAX);
    SET 
      @JSONDATA = N'{"domainId":29,"locales":[{"language":"en","country":"IN"},{"language":"en","country":"AU"}]}';
    SELECT 
      COUNTRY 
    FROM 
      OPENJSON(@JSONDATA) WITH (
        LOCALES NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.locales' AS JSON
      ) CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(LOCALES, '$') WITH (
        COUNTRY NVARCHAR(2) '$.country'
      );
```

Here is the query which runs in **Oracle server**

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  JSON_TABLE(
    '{"domainId":29,"locales":[{"language":"en","country":"IN"},{"language":"en","country":"AU"}]}', 
    '$.locales[*]' COLUMNS (
      -- L_ROWNUM FOR ORDINALITY,
      L_COUNTRY VARCHAR2(10) PATH '$.country'
    )
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Postgres, you can use this:

```
select c.item ->> 'country' as country
from the_table t
  cross join jsonb_array_elements(t.json_column -> 'locales') as c(item);
```

Answer (score -1):

This is an Object type and you should convert it an Array if you want to show this on table.

i.e.:

```
var Array_name = Object.keys(object_name);
```

Then you can use this as Array